# pandas how to ignore column cells that cannot be converted to datetime for calculating time delta

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, series

I have a `df`,

```
doc_date    date_string
2019-06-03  WW0306
2019-06-07  EH0706
2019-08-08  19685
2019-08-09  258
2019-08-10  441573556
```

`doc_date` is of `dateimte64` dtype, `date_string` is `string`, removing non-digit characters,

```
s = df['date_string'].str.replace(r'\D+', '')

doc_date    date_string
2019-06-03  0306
2019-06-07  0706
2019-08-08  19685
2019-08-09  258
2019-08-10  441573556

s1 = to_datetime(s, errors='ignore', format='%d%m')

doc_date    date_string
2019-06-03  1900-06-03
2019-06-07  1900-06-07
2019-08-08  19685
2019-08-09  258
2019-08-10  441573556
```

Here I am wondering how to ignore those rows whose `date_string` cannot be converted to datetime; so I can create a boolean mask as,

```
 c1 = (df.doc_date.dt.dayofyear - s1.dt.dayofyear).abs().le(180)
```

another thing is how to get `c1` the same length as of `s` that any `date_string` that cannot be converted to `datetime` will get `False` in `c1`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `errors='coerce'` for convert non matched pattern values to `NaT` for working datetimelike functions:

```
s1 = to_datetime(s, errors='coerce', format='%d%m')
```

Or more common use (pandas 0.24.2, so different output):

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce', format='%d%m')
print (s1)
0   1900-06-03
1   1900-06-07
2          NaT
3   1900-08-25
4          NaT
Name: date_string, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

All together:

```
#if necessary
#df['doc_date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['doc_date'])

s = df['date_string'].str.replace(r'\D+', '')

s1 = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce', format='%d%m')

c1 = (df.doc_date.dt.dayofyear - s1.dt.dayofyear).abs().le(180)
print (c1)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: how to make `c1` the equal length as `s` here?

Comment: @daiyue - hmmm, it is not same length?